# Does Kafka client send metadata request meaninglessly sometimes?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Conditions:**

- The topic "myTopic" does not exist.
- In `server.properties`,
  `auto.create.topics.enable=false`

**Issue:**
When a message is sent to `myTopic`, Kafka client receives the UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION error. So it begins to update metadata crazily, never stop. Is it reasonable?

```
@RequestMapping("send")
public void hello() {
    template.send("myTopic", "foo1")
            .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                    log.error("send error",ex);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                    log.info("send success={}",result);
                }
            });
}
```

Kafka producer log:

```
17:40:09.408 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9640 : {myTopic3=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
17:40:09.408 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Requesting metadata update for topic myTopic3 due to error UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION
17:40:09.408 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 9636 to MetadataCache{cluster=Cluster(id = N7hvdHK5TK-JgLv8wVpZuA, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null))}
17:40:09.512 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(name='myTopic3')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
17:40:09.513 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9641 : {myTopic3=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
17:40:09.513 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Requesting metadata update for topic myTopic3 due to error UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION
17:40:09.513 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 9637 to MetadataCache{cluster=Cluster(id = N7hvdHK5TK-JgLv8wVpZuA, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null))}
...
...
```

Comment: Did the topic "myTopic" exist and you deleted it recently before executing the code above? If yes, how did you delete the topic?

Comment: @mike from the beginning there is no "myTopic".

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270645/java-apache-kafka-producer-metadata-updater-retry-logic/60324708#60324708

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing logs for myTopic3 if you're not using that topic. But obviously topic doesn't exist, and you keep calling send method, the producer will keep trying, and failing